# Error C2228, though left of .x has a class

Tags: c++, direct3d

I am trying to call class function, while Visual Studio throws above error at me. I have been calling another function in constructor and it works there.

What is worth mentioning, is that GameLoop is static. I have a strange feeling that this might be the cause. If it is, how do I make it work?

```
GameApp::GameApp()
{
    winApi.CreateBasicWindow("---===| Test |===---", 1024, 768, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

    bool err = d3d.BasicInit(winApi.GetWindowHandle(),
                             winApi.GetInstance(),
                             1024,
                             768,
                             60,
                             1,
                             true);

    if(!err)
        MessageBox(0, "Could not initialize DirectX 10.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    winApi.RunMessageLoop(GameLoop);
}

void GameApp::GameLoop()
{
    D3DXCOLOR color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    d3d.Redraw(color); // Error here
}
```

---- edit

Error message

```
Error   1   error C2228: left of '.Redraw' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the error message and location.

Comment: You should include the full text of the error message in you question

Comment: is d3d a nonstatic member variable? if so, whose d3d do you expect GameLoop to redraw?

Comment: Just a guess but `d3d` isn't declared as static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `GameLoop` is `static`, that means it can only access `static` fields. `d3d` is probably not a static field.

You probably made GameLoop static to keep a single instance of GameApp available throughout the code. To do that properly, read up on the singleton pattern, for it probably is what you are looking for.

Comment: Or "Singleton anti-pattern" if you prefer.

Comment: @chris one has to learn why Singletons are awesome before learning why the actually suck :P